# How to bind the window loaded event?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I want to bind the loaded event from my view so tha i can read some settings at the start.  With some searching i made this but it does not work. what am i missing?

the view:

```
<UserControl x:Name="UserControlRegistratie" x:Class="Qbox_0001.Views.RegistratieView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 

             mc:Ignorable="d" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"

             xmlns:intr="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
>
    <intr:Interaction.Triggers>
        <intr:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <intr:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=windowLoadedCommand}"/>
        </intr:EventTrigger>
    </intr:Interaction.Triggers>

    <Grid x:Name="GridRegistratie">
    .....
```

The viewmodel:

```
public class RegistratieViewModel
    {
        public RelayCommand windowLoadedCommand { get; private set; }

        public RegistratieViewModel()
        {
            ...
            //commands
            windowLoadedCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteWindowLoaded, CanExecute);
        }

        private bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        private void ExecuteWindowLoaded(object parameter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("window laden...........");
            //Nothing happens
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you make sure that there is an instance of your RegistratieViewModel in the UserControl's DataContext?

Comment: In my view i have this: (works for the other bindings)

Answer (score 0):

In my view i have this : (works for the other bindings)

```
public partial class RegistratieView : UserControl
    {
        public RegistratieView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new RegistratieViewModel();
        }
    }
```